# How to add a QAction to a map?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I would like to add a QAction to a map in order to add that action to the menu file, so that I could then delete the action and replace it with another QAction in the same spot in the map.

I've tried using removeAction, but it doesn't seem to be working for me and putting it into a map would make it much more efficient. This is what I'm trying to do, but I'm getting casting errors.

`actionMap.emplace(rem, (QAction*)addAction(filePath));`

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please show enough code to provide some context -- a [mcve] is possible.  Also show any compiler error messages verbatim.

Comment: What `addAction()` function does?

Comment: For what it's worth any addAction function I know of returns either a QAction* -- in which case there's no need for the cast -- or void making the cast to QAction* invalid. As already stated, you need to provide a [mcve].